# One big Consolidation sheet

Tags: database, excel, data-warehouse, qlikview

I have about 150 Excel sheets joined together in a consolidation sheet. Every sheet of those 150 have 350 rows. (Some are empty).

I want to analyse this data in Qlikview.

My question is: will it help me to turn this consolidation sheets into a relational database an eventually a datawarehouse?

I habe all the information in one sheet and can just load it into Qlickview, but does it benefit me to make the consolidation sheet into multiple tables?

Answer (score 0):

- to make the changes you will need to import data from xls into database and then export them back into qlikview. but if you can do the import from xls into qlikview is the relation database really necessary?
- about presentation your data - if you want load and combine each sheet as into one consolidation dataset you can do this via `concatenate`

  ```
  Data:
  Load *
  From FileName.xlsx (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1);     

  Concatenate(Data)

  Data:
  Load *
  From FileName.xlsx (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet2);
  ```
- or you can load each sheet as separate dimension and then concatenate them some way

  ```
  Data1:
  Load *
  From FileName.xlsx (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1);

  Data2:
  Load *
  From FileName.xlsx (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet2);
  ```